# How to retain null values in flat file destination in ssis package

Tags: ssis, oledb, ssis-2012, dataflowtask, flatfiledestination

I have created an ssis package. in dataflow task, i am passing data from oledbsource to flat file destination. i want to retain null values in flat file but it is coming blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hadi has provided an example of how to handle NULLS being read from a flatfile.  I understand you want to write NULLs to a flatfile. As has been explained, flatfiles do not have a concept of NULLs. Unlike SQL they do not have datatype.  Everything is a string. A NULL in a flatfile is equal to an empty string.

From your statement

> i want to retain null values in flat file but it is coming blank.

I can only presume that you want to print the text "NULL" into the flatfile.
For that, you can use a Derived Column component. Place it between your OLE DB Source and your Flat File Destination.  Inside the Derived Column component detect the null values and cast them from a true NULL value into a string value "NULL"  using the following ternary expression.

```
ISNULL([MyColumn]) ? "NULL" : [MyColumn]
```

Hope this helps.  If you needed something else, please feel free to clarify your question.

Comment: _"As has been explained, flatfiles do not have a concept of NULLs."_ - This is contrary to my experience: for-all-intents-and-purposes an SSIS Flat File - with specific formatting options - _is_ an RFC 4180-style CSV file, and amongst the CSV-handling community it's commonplace to denote SQL `NULL` by either an omitted value, or as an unquoted `NULL` value (while requiring all non-NULL string values to be quoted, though numeric values don't need quotes), and binary values in `0x`-prefixed base-16. Confusingly, if you do a clipboard copy from SSMS's Results pane you _do_ get unquoted `NULL` too

Comment: NULLs are a idea that only exist inside the context of systems with datatypes, such as databases or programming languages.  Or put more simply, you can't put a database NULL into a flatfile because a flatfile is not a database.  Ultimately if you want to move a database NULL between systems using a flatfile it's up to the flatfile writer and the flatfile reader to agree upon that convention.  They don't always. And that's why we have multiple conventions as you pointed out.  I'd imagine if NULLs could be universally represented in text files, we wouldn't have those inconsitencies.

Answer (score 1):

In flat files there is not difference between null and blanks. so if flat file are readed using an application or another ssis package you have to check that value is not null or empty using functions like `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `IsNull()`

**I.E.:**

In a script component you can check the column value like the following:

```
If Not Row.inCol_IsNull AndAlso _
   Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.InCol) Then

  'Do SomeThing
  Row.OutCol = Row.inCol

  Else

  Row.OutCol_IsNull = True

  En If
```

**OR**

if using an application

```
 If not strValue is nothing andAlso _
    not string.IsNullOrEmpty(strvalue) then

 ' do something
 end If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use derived column transformation in SSIS, Try with the following code. Replace `[ColumnName]` with your column.

```
ISNULL([ColumnName]) ? "NULL" : [ColumnName]
```